# When to use SQLAlchemy .get() vs .filter(Foo.ID == primary_key_id).first()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Just curious about when I would want to use one vs the other. How are they different?

We have our system set up such that we can do this:

```
my_user = User.query().filter(User.ID == 5).first()
```

or

```
my_user = User.query().get(5)
```

Comment: For completeness you can query using db.session.query(MyClass).get(myPk) as well

Comment: Deprecated since version 1.4: The [Query.get()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Query.get) method is considered legacy as of the 1.x series of SQLAlchemy and becomes a legacy construct in 2.0. The method is now available as [Session.get()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.Session.get)
**# legacy usage:**
`user_obj = session.query(User).get(5)`
**1.4 / 2.0 cross-compatible use:**
`user_obj = session.get(User, 5)`

Answer (score 21):

Those two lines are the same thing. Only exceptions raised differ. In fact, `get()` is implemented on top of `one()`. There would be a difference if your `filter()` returned more than a result, but this is indeed not possible in your case.

By the way, SQL does not have a GET operation, it only has SELECT (with optional LIMIT).

---

[sqlalchemy/orm/query.py](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L833):

```
def get(self, ident):
    ...
    return self._get_impl(ident, loading.load_on_ident)
```

[sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py#L165):

```
def load_on_ident(query, key,
                  refresh_state=None, lockmode=None,
                  only_load_props=None):
    ...
    try:
        return q.one()
    except orm_exc.NoResultFound:
        return None
```

[`q.one()` in turn calls `q.one_or_none()`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L2701).

Now compare [`first()`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L2639) with [`one_or_none()`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L2671):

```
def first(self):
    ...
    ret = list(self[0:1])
    if len(ret) > 0:
        return ret[0]
    else:
        return None


def one_or_none(self):
    ...
    ret = list(self)

    l = len(ret)
    if l == 1:
        return ret[0]
    elif l == 0:
        return None
    else:
        raise orm_exc.MultipleResultsFound(
            "Multiple rows were found for one_or_none()")
```

Therefore, `first()` executes a SELECT with a LIMIT, `one_or_none()` executes an unlimited SELECT. But, as we already said, either with or without LIMIT the result of the query cannot change, therefore the two are equivalent.

Answer (score 18):

One important addition to Andrea Corbellini's answer:  `get` can provide a performance boost by retrieving the object from memory if it already exists in the SQLAlchemy session.

[sqlalchemy/orm/query.py](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L776):

> `Query.get` is special in that it provides direct
> access to the identity map of the owning `Session`.
> If the given primary key identifier is present
> in the local identity map, the object is returned
> directly from this collection and no SQL is emitted,
> unless the object has been marked fully expired.
> If not present,
> a `SELECT` is performed in order to locate the object.

Additionally, `get` will do a database I/O (i.e. `SELECT` statement) to refresh the object, if it has expired within the session:

[sqlalchemy/orm/query.py](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/7d96ad4d535dc02a8ab1384df1db94dea2a045b5/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L776):

> `Query.get` also will perform a check if
> the object is present in the identity map and
> marked as expired - a `SELECT`
> is emitted to refresh the object as well as to
> ensure that the row is still present.
> If not, `sqlalchemy.orm.exc.ObjectDeletedError` is raised.

Comment: this is documented [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/session_basics.html#is-the-session-a-cache)

Answer (score 2):

`get()` is only used to return a single mapped instance, not multiple instances or individual column constructs, and strictly on a single primary key value.

In this way, `filter()` and `filter_by()` will be diffrent

Answer (score 1):

The first (`.filter()`) is more general: you can construct any conditional for any set of columns.  The latter is a shortcut for the common case of a lookup by primary key.

*(note: this is a first impression; I haven't used SQLAlchemy, though I do have many years of programming experience)*